# Can WSO2 be used to receive email?

Tags: linux, email, wso2

I am completely new to WSO2 , I have a requirement for receiving mails in a UNIX server.

Linux mail listener is not able to log received mails in system mail box .

Is it possible to  use WSO2 to receive mail?

Comment: This is a programming website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a proxy service in WSO2 ESB that will receive it's messages via mail transport.

Think to enable mail transport in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml :

```
<transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener" />
```

To define your proxy, you can have a look in wso2 doc : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/MailTo+Transport

You can also have a look there : http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.fr/2013/10/how-to-receive-emails-to-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Hello Jean, There are many products for WSO2 like carbon, data services server and many more , which one i need to install to get mail functionality done . Please help me out . Thanks !!!!

Comment: the sample and documentation links refers to WSO2 ESB

Comment: Hi Jean Thanks !! for the help , i have installed WSO2 now . But while i am going to set proxy in admin console i am not finding any add option for the proxy in manage console . Under manage console its only showing shutdown/restart option . Please put your view on this , it will be really help full . Thanks !!